# How can I use objects ( not string ) in django email module

Tags: python, django

I'm developing some alert system.

I want to use objects with django Email.

as the code below; 'sshFailResult' is the object from some tasks.

but that email send 'sshFailResult' of string type.

how can I use objects with Email module ?

thanks in advance.

```py
sshFailResult=[]
for i in range(0,sizeOfList):
    sshFailResult=sshFailResult +[preSshFailResult[i].split("=>")[0]
    i +=1

sshFailEmail = EmailMessage('[SOC SYSTEM]','sshFailResult',to=['myEmailAddr'])
if sshFailResult:
    sshFailEmail.send()
else:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes around `sshFailResult` in the line. Update it to:

`sshFailEmail = EmailMessage('[SOC SYSTEM]', sshFailResult, to=['myEmailAddr'])`